# Does a swing filterable JList component exist?

Tags: java, swing, filter, jlist

For a specific screen, I'm looking for a `JList` that I could filter (the same way you can filter a `JTable` using a `RowFilter`)

Is there a good implementation of this kind of component anywhere here in the wild (and do you have an experience with it) or do I have to code it myself ?

(it is not that long to do, but if there is any valid implementation, I would be happy to use it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I'm sure that the SwingX components provide this. Check out [JXList](http://swinglabs.java.sun.com/hudson/job/SwingX%20Continuous%20Build/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXList.html).

You can get SwingX from [here](http://swinglabs.org/).

Comment: just updating the link: the home of SwingX is http://swingx.java.net (swinglabs.org is dysfunctional)

Comment: SwingX is dead now, as are all those links including the java.net site.  Using the `JTable` approach in Adamski's answer is the correct solution.

Answer (score 6):

You could consider using a single column `JTable` instead of a `JList`.  If you follow this approach you'll get filtering and sorting for free (providing you're using JDK 6).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO [glazedlists](http://sites.google.com/site/glazedlists/) should do filtering as well as sorting for JTable, JList and JComboBox.