# Display arraylist search method results into a  JList

Tags: swing, jlist

Currently I have an arraylist holding data for customers, the data is then displayed in a jlist in another class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a swing filterable JList component exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362122/does-a-swing-filterable-jlist-component-exist)

Comment: unrelated to your question: a) don't size/position componnets manually, instead use a LayoutManager b) don't use setXXSize ever

Answer (score 1):

Don't search the `JList`, search its `ListModel`. The default implementation, `DefaultListModel`, has an `Ennumeration` that's convenient for traversing the entries. If need be, the model for your dependent `JList` can register as a listener to the other's model in order to stay synchronized.