# Adding lots of items into a ListModel without blocking the UI

Tags: java, swing

I've implemented a search of lots of items (hundreds) in a JList using Lucene - when someone types in the search box it performs a search and displays the results in a JList. It does this by adding and removing the items from the underlying JList model when each character is typed, but this approach blocks the UI (because adding something to a ListModel has to be performed on the EDT.) The search is very quick but it's the adding and removing of items that takes the time.

How would I approach the problem to not block the EDT while the model is being modified?

The length of the lag isn't huge - it's definitely at the state where it's usable at the moment, just not really as *snappy* as I'd like (for want of a better word.) I'm expecting people on less powerful machines than mine to run the software though hence my interest in sorting the issue.

Other details:

- I have profiled the application, the lag is definitely caused by adding / removing lots of items. A typical step could see any number of items getting added or removed, from a few to hundreds. For instance, if I search for the letter "x" in the text box then most of the items will get removed since few contain that letter. If I then remove the letter all the items will be added again. If I search for a more common term, "the" for instance, then just a few items may be removed since the bulk of them contain that term.
- I'm not dealing with strings directly, but they're relatively simple objects made up of just a few strings (Song to be precise made up of things like title, author, lyrics etc.), and they're all cached using SoftReferences where possible (so assume none of these objects are being created or destroyed, they shouldn't be for a typical user.)

Comment: How many items are you adding or removing from the JList at a time in a typical step? What type of objects are being added to the JList? Strings? Something more complex? Is there a performance hit from object creation? And have you profiled this?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've posted some weak suggestions in an answer.

Comment: Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362122/does-a-swing-filterable-jlist-component-exist

Comment: Disclaimer: I have no knowledge about Lucene - just: a Lucene-backed RowFilter sounds like an interesting add-on to SwingX :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but I wonder if your best solution is simply not to add hundreds of items. There's no way that the user will be able to or want to scroll through this many items in a JList, and so perhaps your smartest move is to limit how many items added to a reasonable number, say 20 or so.

I think of this similar to a word processor displaying a document on the screen or other immediate "look-up" components I've used in the past. If the document is large, often the whole thing isn't loaded into memory but rather somehow cached to disk. If you have no choice but to load a lot of items, then perhaps you can take this portion of the model "off-line" show a wait modal dialog, load the items off the EDT and then get the model back on line and then releasing the modal dialog.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a good approach to use in general - I had thought of it but since the items in the list are sorted alphabetically, chances are the user might well want to scroll through that many items since they're sensibly organised. Perhaps some variant on this idea where only 20 items are initially displayed but more added if the user scrolls would work though. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @berry: you're welcome and best of luck. Regardless of what happens, please come back to this thread to let us know what you eventually do.

Comment: Shall do - it may be a while before I get a chance to have a play around though!

Answer (score 1):

I think that easiest way would be to use [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) instead of [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), add [RowFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) to `JTable`, then there aren't reason to `add/remove/modify` numbers of `Items`

for `add/remove/modify` numbers of `Items` in the `XxxModel` on the background is there [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: SwingWorker won't work here since the task that's taking the time is the one that needs to execute on the EDT. But thanks, I'll take a look at JTable and see how that compares!